# How can I have an object of a derived class "reference" members of an instance of the base class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Suppose I have a class `Foo` whose implementation involves a large object. I want to extend the functionality of `Foo`, and so I decide to write a class `Bar` which inherits `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
protected:
    int bigobject;
public:
    Foo() : bigobject(1) { }
    int get() { return bigobject; }
    void set(int x) { bigobject = x; }
};


class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar(Foo& f) { /* ??? */ }
    void multiply(int factor) { bigobject *= factor; }
};
```

As you can see, I've left the constructor blank. This is because what I'd like to do is have the base members of any `Bar` object be references to members of an existing `Foo` instance.  In other words, I want the code:

```
Foo f;
f.set(5);
std::cout << "f is " << f.get() << std::endl;

Bar b(f);
std::cout << "b is " << b.get() << std::endl;
b.multiply(2);
std::cout << "b is " << b.get() << std::endl;
std::cout << "f is " << f.get() << std::endl;
```

To result in:

```
f is 5
b is 5
b is 10
f is 10
```

So that `f` and the base part of `b` share the same memory space. This is to avoid copying `bigobject` any time I want to instantiate a `Bar`. In informal terms, I want a `Bar` object `b` to be a "view" of a `Foo` object `f`. Calling any of `Foo`'s member methods would change `f`, but I could also define more methods as part of `Bar` which would change `f` as well.

Now, I could declare a global "storage" variable as such:

```
int bigobject_storage = 1;

class Foo {
protected:
    int& bigobject;
public:
    Foo() : bigobject(bigobject_storage) { }
    int get() { return bigobject; }
    void set(int x) { bigobject = x; }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    void multiply(int factor) { bigobject *= factor; }
};
```

To get the functionality I want, but this seems hackish and leaks the implementation. So, is there an idiomatic C++ way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[David Wheeler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wheeler_%28computer_scientist%29) seems to be responsible for the quote

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection.

This applies in your case: Have your base class `Foo` store a [smart] pointer to the big object in question and share the corresponding pointer across the relevant instances. When default constructing a `Foo` object a big object is allocated and pointed to. When copying `Foo` objects, the new `Foo` object is set to reference the same big object as the original. Note, however, that this means that the `Foo` bases behave more like references to each other than values.

In practical terms, you'd probably use something like this:

```
class Foo {
protected: // I don't really believe in protected data members! Don't use them!
    std::shared_ptr<int> bigobject;
public:
    Foo(): bigobject(new int()) {}
    Foo(Foo const& other): bigobject(other.bigobject()) {}
    // ...
 };

 Bar::Bar(Foo& other): Foo(other) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: +1 And if you wanted to optionally keep the allocation out of `Foo` (a semi-odd version of the OP's "hack"), an alternate constructor taking a `shared_ptr<int>` would suffice as well to supply it externally. Nice answer.

Comment: Great, thanks! This is the second question I have asked this week whose result depended on initialization lists. I think I'll read up some more on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using nothing more than OOP concepts.

All you need to do is a pointer to the object, and the polymorphism will do the job.

You don't have yo change nothing in your code, nor you have to give Bar a copy of Bar, all you need to do is call the constructor of the base class (although that is done automatically, in the case of the default constructor), in your derived class.

Something like this:

```
class Foo {
protected:
    int bigobject;
public:
    Foo() : bigobject(1) { }
    int get() { return bigobject; }
    void set(int x) { bigobject = x; }
};


class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar() : Foo() { }
    void multiply(int factor) { bigobject *= factor; }
};
```

The trick is in deciding how you want to "view" the object.
Because Foo is the base class of Bar, Bar has everything that Foo has. In other words, Bar is Foo plus what you define in Bar. So a Foo pointer pointing to Bar will behave as a Foo object, even if it is pointing to Bar.

The code would be like this:

```
Bar b();
/* 
/* f and b point to the same object.
/* But, to the compiler, f does'nt know anything of b and its methods,
/* because f is a pointer to Foo.
 */
Foo *f = &b;
f->set(5)
std::cout << "f is " << f->get() << std::endl;

std::cout << "b is " << b.get() << std::endl;
b.multiply(2);
std::cout << "b is " << b.get() << std::endl;
std::cout << "f is " << f->get() << std::endl;
```

To have this result:

```
f is 5
b is 5
b is 10
f is 10
```

And even you are saving the memory of one object, because you are using the same object, but viewed as different classes. That is polymorphism.